# powershell cannot find system share when running scripts

Tags: powershell, network-share

When I run the script on the computer with the share using UNC path it works; e.g.:

```
powershell.exe -ep bypass -file \\WIN7\SomeShare\myscript.ps1
```

When I run the script on every other computer I get "cannot find the path specified". I have checked the permissions and even made them overly verbose to get it to work. I have set the permissions for everyone to read write and run the script but still does not work. I can see the share is set up and network discovery can find it, but powershell cannot. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you running this script remotely via a pssession? If so, you are most likely encountering the [double hop problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/).

Comment: Let us know if the linked post doesn't solve the problem.